# Spring Boot: Change Port for Web Application

Tags: spring-boot

I am currently trying to create a web application with Spring Boot. I need to host my application to localhost:8081. How do I change the port?

Comment: Edit in application.properties file as **server.port = 8081**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually you want to change `server.port` and you can change it in many different ways as described http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Examples:

- in your application.properties (in or outside the jar)
- command line

  java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

and much more

Comment: Is there a solution for passing params to gradle?

Comment: When using command line params like -Dserver.port=$PORT will take priority over application.properties

Answer (score 11):

By default spring boot uses port 8080, BUT you can change the port just by adding the following code line in your main() like this:

```
System.getProperties().put( "server.port", *YOUR_PORT_NUMBER_GOES_HERE* );
```

*e.g*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.getProperties().put( "server.port", 8181 );  //8181 port is set here
    SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);
}
```

**OR**

You can configure it in your application.properties file like so:

```
server.port=8181
```

If you DON'T have an application.properties file in your spring-boot application, you can go ahead and create one. Right-click on the **src/java/resources** folder and go to **New-> Other-> General and choose 'File'** then name as: **application.properties**

Any other configurations you might need are listed here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. These properties are also configured in the application.properties file.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you want to change server.port and you can change it in many different ways as described 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Put ***server.port=9000*** in your application.properties

Answer (score 3):

In your application.properties file, just add one line

```
server.port = 8080
```

And for more configurations you can refer [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-change-the-http-port) on port

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the embedded tomcat server, you can configure the EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean yourself in your Application class annotated with @SpringBootApplication.

This will give you options to customize your tomcat server, example configuration

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setPort(9000);
    factory.setSessionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notfound.html"));
    return factory;
}
```

You could also do the same for Jetty, using the JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean, or for Undertow using the UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory .

Official documentation found here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using STS, you can do it following below steps:

- Go to Boot Dashboard view, you'll see your Boot app, say **myApp1**

[image]

- Right click and click on Open Config. This should open Run Time
  Configuration section.
- Go to Argument tab and add parameter server.port=, like in the example below, a custom port **9091** is added.

[image]

- Start the app and if everything is good, you'll see the desired port
  on Boot dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to your application.properties file and type **server.port=8081**
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuznC.png)

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties you can define port that will be received from environment variable like :

server.port=${PORT:8200}