# How to change default port in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, port

I have a Springboot application and want to change the default port, I am using the kotlin language.

I have deployed it on a server and there it works fine, but when unning locally I get this stack trace:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9093]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]

Plus the following warning message:

> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9093 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
>
> Action:
>
> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9093, or configure this application to listen on another port.

I have changed the port by my `application.properties` file:

```
server.port = 9093
```

There is an explicit reason that I have chosen for port 9093, because that is the only port I have acces to on the companies development server, I don't want to change the ports all the time when switching from running locallyand running in the cloud. The default port 8080 works fine.

**So my questions is: How to change the default port in Springboot when running locally?**

Comment: It appears that the port is changing correctly but that you have some other service already running on port `9093` locally.

Comment: Just override it when launching the application `java -jar <your-jar-here> --server.port=8080`. However even better will be to create environment specific configurations and use a profile to switch/select the right one.

Comment: I actually saw it right now, I was running one instance from my IDE and another on command line. But forgot it was there, so that was the problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your comment, that is an actual usefull command I was not aware off. +1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot: Change Port for Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219255/spring-boot-change-port-for-web-application)